# Cordova camera returning guid not b64 or path w/ "xxx.png". Need file for upload

Tags: javascript, cordova, blob, cordova-plugins, file-access

New to Cordova (and JS), please be gentle.

I'm trying to get my app taking photos, and everything works fine until it's time to upload them to the server.  Pics take fine, edit works (if edit selected).

What I am getting though, is imageData (variable from documentation) with what appears to be a url encoded guid. (I tried an atob on it just to be sure - it is not b64 - which is clear, but just in case).  The documentation even has a section that says:

```
function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {
// Uncomment to view the base64 encoded image data //<--- this...
// console.log(imageData);
....
}
```

but if I look at it *right* there, before anything happens, I get something like:

```
blob:http%3A//localhost%3A4400/5d142c27-3908-4db4-87dd-0a22d6e5fd62
```

I've tried sending Camera.DestinationType.DATA_URL, FILE_URI, etc.. all of them.  I always get this - the options don't seem to matter.

So, I have a blob.  If I try to get it with an xhr request, I get a 500 error.  If I try to get it with the file helper addon (window.FilePath.... I can't remember the name, but it's cordova), it doesn't work.  I don't think that one likes blobs or something.

If I try to navigate to the location, I simply get:

```
Cannot GET /5d142c27-3908-4db4-87dd-0a22d6e5fd62
```

If I try to navigate to something like:

```
content://media/external/images/media/2/d085fb44-de36-46ed-93a4-73f140f4bc3d
```

it also fails.

if I split the GUID and atob it(replacing the "-"), I wind up with something like:

```
q×xÓMz-÷_u-ã®´-iÞ
```

So I don't think that's it...

I've been trying to get this figured out for hours now.  Can someone point me in the right direction please?  I have looked at other articles, but nothing seems to be working.  I'm pretty sure it's because of the format I'm getting returned.

If this is simple, my apologies.  I'm new to the OS, language, and cordova, and trying my best here. Just not sure my next steps.

If more code is needed, please let me know and I'll update it.  It's all still pretty much boilerplate though.

Answer (score 0):

If anyone else winds up here, this is A correct fix (as of today).  I found it at: [Using PhoneGap, How to get base64 image data of the photo chosen from photo library in iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11188599/using-phonegap-how-to-get-base64-image-data-of-the-photo-chosen-from-photo-libr), credit to revathy-durairajan:

create this function.

```
function encodeImageUri(imageUri) {
var c = document.createElement('canvas');
var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
var img = new Image();
img.onload = function () {
    c.width = this.width;
    c.height = this.height;
    ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
};
img.src = imageUri;
var dataURL = c.toDataURL("image/jpeg");
return dataURL;
```

}

Call this function with the imageData

```
var testtest = encodeImageUri(imageData);
```

done.